# Can't access ElasticSearch through local port forward

Tags: port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, elasticsearch

I'm stuck at connecting to my SearchGuard-proteced ElasticSearch instance inside the company network from my local machine at home. I'm using a local SSH forward same as I got working for a phpMyAdmin instance.

My ~/.ssh/config contains these:

```
Host workstation-forward-phpmyadmin
    LocalForward localhost:8080 $WORKSTATION:443
    HostKeyAlias $GATEWAY
    Hostname $GATEWAY
    ExitOnForwardFailure yes
    User oschluet

Host workstation-forward-elasticsearch
    LocalForward localhost:9200 $WORKSTATION:9200
    HostKeyAlias $GATEWAY
    Hostname $GATEWAY
    ExitOnForwardFailure yes
    User oschluet
```

I engage these in a `screen`-session like so:
    `ssh workstation-forward-elasticsearch` or `ssh workstation-forward-phpmyadmin`
and detach the screen.

Now I can access the phpMyAdmin through my browser by accessing `https://localhost:8080` or use telnet to talk to the web server directly. 
Unfortunately there seems to be an issue with ElasticSearch in this regard. From a different machine inside the company network I can access the ElasticSearch like this:

```
oschluet@ravenwood:~$ curl -k https://$WORKSTATION:9200 --user $user:$pass
{
  "name" : "redacted",
  "cluster_name" : "redacted",
  "cluster_uuid" : "redacted",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.1.1",
    "build_hash" : "5395e21",
    "build_date" : "2016-12-06T12:36:15.409Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.3.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Using the same credentials locally yields nothing:

```
[oschlueter@B5400 ~]$ curl -k https://localhost:9200 --user $user:$pass
# nothing happens
```

Using no credentials:

```
oschluet@ravenwood:~$ curl -k https://$WORKSTATION:9200
Unauthorized

[oschlueter@B5400 ~]$ curl -k https://localhost:9200
# again nothing
```

However telnet opens a connection:

```
[oschlueter@B5400 ~]$ telnet localhost 9200
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I tried having ElasticSearch listen on the ip address, the hostname and `0.0.0.0` which all allowed me to connect from the other machine inside the network however no connection from my local machine could be established. I'm admin of $WORKSTATION and of my local machine. Could anyone help me locate the issue please?

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue.  Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: I don't believe I did and I can't recall what I did instead. Good luck tho!